# javascript grid help

Tags: javascript, loops, grid

I am working on looping through a few grid items and was hoping someone could help me find a way to figure out how to get to the items that I need and possibly I will better understand how to access the items in the grid. So here is the grid.

```
[0]  [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]
[5]  [6]  [7]  [8]  [9]
[10] [11] [12] [13] [14]
[15] [16] [17] [18] [19]
[20] [21] [22] [23] [24]
```

This is basically a 5x5 grid, however it could be any size but I just used this for the example. There are two ways I would like to loop through this. The first one being in this order:

```
0,1,2,3,4,9,14,19,24,23,22,21,20,15,10,5,6,7,8,13,18,17,16,11,12
```

Basically all that is doing is going around the outside starting from the top left. The next way I would want to loop through that is through the same exact values except in reverse order (basically inside out instead of outside in) and actually thinking about this now I could just loop through the first method backwards. If anyone can help me with this it would be great. I really want to learn more on how to loop through items in crazy arrangements like this.

Comment: What is the output from "inside out"? is it 0,5,10..etc or 24,23,22,etc?

Comment: Like I said before it is the exact values I have listed except in reverse order so 12,11,16...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
function n(i, w, h)
{
    if (i < w)
        return i;
    if (i < w + h-1)
        return w-1 + (i-w+1)*w;
    if (i < w + h-1 + w-1)
        return w-1 + (h-1)*w - (i - (w + h-1 - 1));
    if (i < w + h-1 + w-1 + h-2)
        return (h - (i - (w + w-1 + h-1 - 2)))*w;
    var r = n(i - (w-1)*2 - (h-1)*2, w-2, h-2);
    var x = r % (w-2);
    var y = Math.floor(r / (w-2));
    return (y+1)*w + (x+1);
}
```

accepts as input

- `i`: Index of the item you're looking for
- `w`: Width of the grid
- `h`: Height of the grid

and returns the corresponding element of the grid assuming that clock-wise spiral traversal.

The implementation simply checks if we're on the top side `(i<w)`, on the downward right side `(i<w+h-1)` and so on and for these cases it computes the cell element explicitly.
If we complete one single trip around the spiral then it calls recursively itself to find the element in the inner `(w-2)*(h-2)` grid and then extracts and adjusts the two coordinates considering the original grid size.

This is much faster for big grids than just iterating and emulating the spiral walk, for example computing `n(123121, 1234, 3012)` is immediate while the complete grid has 3712808 elements and a walk of 123121 steps would require quite a long time.

Comment: That works great. Can you please elaborate more on how you came up with this. I would like to do some things just like this but I seem to have problems coming up with the logic like that.

Comment: @ngreenwood6 - the only way to arrive at that kind of code from the original problem statement is to observe the pattern. With the pattern in hand, you then have a finite behavior that can be translated into code. As you say, you know "what to do", but then you need to automate it. Once you can describe the pattern verbally, you can then notate it (as in my answer), and then code it. Note that you have implementation choices. @6502 chose to use recursion, which is a fine choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the "walking" method.  Less efficient, but it works.

```
var arr = new Array();
for(var n=0; n<25; n++) arr.push(n);

var coords = new Array(); 

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
     if( x > 4 ) {
          x = 0;
          y++;
     }

     coords[i] = {'x': x, 'y': y};

     x++;
}

// okay, coords contain the coordinates of each item in arr

// need to move along the perimeter until a collision, then turn.

// start at 0,0 and move east.

var dir = 0; // 0=east, 1=south, 2=west, 3=north.
var curPos = {'x': 0, 'y': 0};
var resultList = new Array();

for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++) {
     // record the current position in results
     var resultIndex = indexOfCoords(curPos, coords);

     if(resultIndex > -1) {
         resultList[x] = arr[resultIndex];
     }
     else {
         resultList[x] = null;
     }

     // move the cursor to a valid position
     var tempCurPos = movePos(curPos, dir);

     var outOfBounds = isOutOfBounds(tempCurPos, coords);
     var itemAtTempPos = arr[indexOfCoords(tempCurPos, coords)];
     var posInList = resultList.indexOf( itemAtTempPos );

     if(outOfBounds || posInList > -1) {
          dir++;
          if(dir > 3) dir=0;
          curPos = movePos(curPos, dir);
     }
     else {
          curPos = tempCurPos;
     }
}


/* int indexOfCoords
 *
 * Searches coordList for a match to myCoords.  If none is found, returns -1;
 */
function indexOfCoords(myCoords, coordsList) {
    for(var i=0; i<coordsList.length; i++) {
        if(myCoords.x == coordsList[i].x && myCoords.y == coordsList[i].y) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

/* obj movePos
 *
 * Alters currentPosition by incrementing it 1 in the direction provided.
 * Valid directions are 0=east, 1=south, 2=west, 3=north
 * Returns the resulting coords as an object with x, y.
 */
function movePos(currentPosition, direction) {
    var newPosition = {'x':currentPosition.x, 'y':currentPosition.y};
    if(direction == 0) {
        newPosition.x++;
    }
    else if(direction == 1) {
        newPosition.y++;
    }
    else if(direction == 2) {
        newPosition.x--;
    }
    else if(direction == 3) {
        newPosition.y--;
    }

    return newPosition;
}

/* bool isOutOfBounds
 *
 * Compares the x and y coords of a given position to the min/max coords in coordList.
 * Returns true if the provided position is outside the boundaries of coordsList.
 *
 * NOTE: This is just one, lazy way of doing this.  There are others.
 */
function isOutOfBounds(position, coordsList) {
    // get min/max
    var minx=0, miny=0, maxx=0, maxy=0;
    for(var i=0; i<coordsList.length; i++) {
        if(coordsList[i].x > maxx) maxx = coordsList[i].x;
        else if(coordsList[i].x < minx) minx = coordsList[i].x;

        if(coordsList[i].y > maxy) maxy = coordsList[i].y;
        else if(coordsList[i].y < miny) miny = coordsList[i].y;
    }

    if(position.x < minx || position.x > maxx || position.y < miny || position.y > maxy) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

This will move through the grid in a direction until it hits the bounds or an item already in the results array, then turn clockwise.  It's pretty rudimentary, but I think it would do the job.  You could reverse it pretty simply.

Here's a working example: http://www.imakewidgets.com/test/walkmatrix.html

Comment: I didnt test this but I thank you for adding in your solution to my problem although it doesnt seem complete (missing functions).

Comment: The missing functions should be easy to write, but I'll probably add them when I'm on a normal computer.  The hard part is the concept, which I _did_ cover.

Comment: Altered the code to include everything.  A working example link is also provided.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a way to represent the traversal pattern.

Given an NxM matrix (e.g. 5x5), the pattern is

```
GENERAL       5x5
-------     -------
N right        5
M-1 down       4
N-1 left       4
M-2 up         3
N-2 right      3
M-3 down       2
N-3 left       2
M-4 up         1
N-4 right      1
```

This says move 5 to the right, 4 down, 4 left, 3 up, 3 right, 2 down, 2 left, 1 up, 1 right. The step size shifts after each two iterations.

So, you can track the current "step-size" and the current direction while decrementing N, M until you reach the end.

IMPORTANT: make sure to write down the pattern for a non-square matrix to see if the same pattern applies.

Comment: Sorry but i did not find this answer very helpful as I already knew what needed to be done just couldnt figure out how to reach the end result.

Comment: this is the link between the "what" and the "how". it defines the pattern in a way that you can then translate into code. Were you expecting someone to write your program for you?

Comment: This is going to end up a more compact/efficient solution than mine, I think, but as you say, it may be more involved for non-square matrices. Interesting problem :)